# Working copy tortoisesvn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've recently started working with tortoisesvn:
I managed to setup an svn repository and import my project

The project is shared on a network drive every one has his own username and password

All the tutorials say to checkout the project in a new folder which will be the working copy, but what about the main project file? when will I used it again? (when saving to the working copy should it save also to the main project?)

Another concept question I don't understand is:
The path to test the project should be the working copy? So that everyone can test his own changes before committing. So how can I see the whole project and not only my working copy?

Thank you

Comment: There's no such thing as "main project" in Subversion. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: From the tutorials I followed, I add the repo-browser to my project, then create a new folder and checkout on this folder this folder will be my working copy, is that correct?

Comment: "I add the repo-browser to my project" - This doesn't make any sense (it's just a program, how can you add a program to your project). When you check out you get a working copy, that part's correct. If those tutorials are not clear, perhaps you should just check the official documentation.

Comment: @Guest012393 when referencing "the tutorials you followed", it's very helpful for us if you can link to those tutorials so that we can see the exact steps and language used.

Answer (score 1):

- **NEVER** place and use Working Copy or Repository on (Windows) network drive - it's a direct way to headache, nightmare and disasters
- Read and understand at least SVN Book - now you show only misunderstanding and lack of knowledge in basic SCM principles and SVN-lingua

Working Copy isn't some high-level magic, it's ordinary directory tree with your usual files (it just have some additional metadata, which allow to implement VCS-functionality)